# In PHP7 with FreeTDS/MSSQL, Chinese character got corrupted if parameter binding is used,

Tags: sql-server, php-7, freetds

### Repro Script

```
$dbh = new \PDO("dblib:host=xxx;dbname=test;charset=utf8","test","test");
$str1 = '中文测试';

// Snippet 1: With parameter binding
$sql = "INSERT INTO TEST (text) VALUES (:text)";
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindValue(':text',$str1); // or $stmt->bindParam(':text',$str1,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();

// Snippet 2: Text in SQL
$sql = "INSERT INTO TEST (text) VALUES ('".$str1."')";
$dbh->exec($sql);
```

### Problem Description

In PHP 7,

For Snippet 1 - The characters ended up corrupted (Mojibake) in the database.

For Snippet 2 - Everything works fine.

In PHP 5.5, both snippets are working as expected.

We found this out when we upgrade PHP 5.5 to PHP 7.

*So the question is why Snippet 1 does not work in PHP 7 setup?*

## Others Information

### Bad Setup (PHP 7)

```
Ubuntu:  Linux 3.19.0-25-generic #26~14.04.1-Ubuntu
PHP (from APT): 7.0.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.2
  with builtin pdo_dblib:  7.0.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.2
freetds (from APT): 0.91-6.1build1
```

### Good Setup (PHP 5.5)

```
Ubuntu: Linux 3.19.0-25-generic #26~14.04.1-Ubuntu
php (from APT): 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.14
  with builtin pdo_dblib: 1.0.1
freetds (from APT):  0.91-5
```

#### freetds configuration in both setups

```
/etc/freetds.config (both PHP 5.5 and 7 installation)
-------
tds version = 8.0
```

Comment: This won't fix the problem, but TDS Version 8.0 is deprecated and shouldn't be used. Use 7.1 or 7.2. It's a long story: http://www.freetds.org/userguide/choosingtdsprotocol.htm

Comment: I am afraid the 8.0/7.1/7.2 is not the key.  It's the same when changed to 7.1/7.2. In addition, If we remove the freetds.config all together, all four setups (PHP {5.5, 7} * Snippet {1,2}) breaks and give mojibake.   Currently only 1 out of 4 setup, PHP 7 * Snippet 1, does not work as expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok it's actually an known bug - https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=72414
And fixed in PHP 7.0.12.